# В чём различие в способах передачи атрибута в директиву?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

На страничке есть элемент с атрибутом

```
some-attr="Hello Habr!"
```

В директиву его значение передаётся двумя способами:

1. через scope
2. через attrs.someAttr

В директиве эти значения выводятся тоже двумя способами:

1. через template:

   "{{someAttr}}-{{qwerty}}",
2. через консоль:

   console.log('qwerty', qwerty);
   console.log('someAttr', someAttr);

Мне не понятно почему в первом случае не выводится qwerty, а во-втором случае не выводится someAttr. Я надеялся, что и qwerty, и someAttr выведутся в обоих случаях

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4b4US/377/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В темплейте qwerty не выводится, т.к. переменная не определена в scope, в коде ниже она определена в функции link и выводится.
2. someAttr в функции link нигде не определена, поэтому ругается ошибкой ReferenceError: someAttr is not defined

Надеюсь комментарии в коде внесут ясность что происходит в директиве.

```js
angular.module('helloHabrahabr', [])
    .directive('habraHabr', function() {        
        return {
            template:"{{some}}-{{qwerty}}", //тут выводятся значения из scope
            scope:{
                some:'@someAttr' //тут передача значения some-attr в scope.some
            },
            
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
             var qwerty = attrs.someAttr; //получение значения из some-attr              
              //scope.some = attrs.someAttr; //можно закомментировать some:'@someAttr' в scope и раскомментировать это
              
              scope.qwerty = 10; //qwerty теперь равно 10
              
              console.log('qwerty', qwerty);
              console.log('someAttr', someAttr);// someAttr is not defined он нигде не определен в этой функции link
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="helloHabrahabr">
        <span habra-habr="hello" some-attr="Hello Habr!"></span>   
</div>
```

Также почитайте [документацию](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) по директивам

Comment: Спасибо, стало понятнее. но всё равно не понятно почему второй console.log не выводт переменную из скоупа: http://jsfiddle.net/4b4US/378/

Comment: эта функция срабатывает до создания scope, добавь после console.log  `alert("test");`, и убедитесь (до нажатия ок), что данные из scope еще не отрисовались, а функция вызвалась. В документации по функции link сказано: `It is executed after the template has been cloned and is where directive logic will be put.`

Comment: @MrFylypenko, не совсем так. Проблема именно в связывании через `@`. Если использовать например `=` то значение уже будет доступно. А уж если взять одну из последних версий ангуляра, а не 1.1 как в пример - то все будет работать как и ожидалось